# Как передать значение var Jsp в Controller Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

Моя проблема: я делаю проект "социальная сеть" и сейчас я занимаюсь списком друзей и пользователей. Когда я вывожу список пользователей, я так же вывожу и самого себя. Именно это я и пытаюсь исправить. Теперь к делу.

У меня есть такой блок в jsp. Это страница пользователя. После входа в аккаунт, контроллер передает объект в атрибут `${user}`.

```
<div class="info-block">
        
        <c:set var = "user" value="${user}"/>
        <c:set var ="userId" value="${user.getId()}"/>   //мне нужно значение этой переменной

        <div class="nickname">
            <b><c:out value="${user.getNickname()}"/></b>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <b>
                Пол: <c:out value="${user.getGender()}" default="Не указано"/><br>
                Возраст: <c:out value="${user.getAge()}" default="Не указано"/><br>
                Дата рождения: <c:out value="${user.getBirthday()}" default="Не указано"/>
            </b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть такая кнопка в меню

```
<a href="/view/friends.html">
    <div class="menu-block">
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="../images/friends.png" alt="friends">
        </div>
        <div class="menu-text">Друзья</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

После нажатия на эту кнопку я попадаю на свой контроллер, который должен взять значение переменной `userId`. (не понимаю как) и вызвать метод, который достанет из бд список пользователей, кроме пользователя, который будет этот список смотреть.

```
@GetMapping("/friends.html")
public String getUsersList(Model model) {
    String id = String.valueOf(model.getAttribute("user.getId()")); // в этой строке мне нужно как-то достать значение userId
    List<User> userList = userController.getUserList(id); // метод достает всех пользователей, кроме указанного id
    model.addAttribute("user", userList);
    return "friends";
}
```

Если возможно, хотел бы получить развернутый ответ почему так не работает. Возможно есть более удобные способы это сделать и я просто теряю время, так что мне очень нужен совет. Спасибо

Comment: Я может не совсем понял вопрос, но по моему вы используете Thymeleaf и говорите о переменных языком jsp, что в принципе не совместимо.

Comment: List<User> userList = userController.getUserList(id);
.... Здесь нужно перебрать лист или исключить выборку в БД по id и передавать в качестве атрибута.... 
 model.addAttribute("user", userList); // Здесь

Comment: @VitaliyM.V. я использую JSTL

Comment: Тогда тут какая-то "каша"... Я могу написать пример - подсказку, а разбираться вам придётся самостоятельно, начиная с анотаций: 
 @GetMapping("/{id}/list") // в том случае, если id передаётся в адресной строке. Например: http://localhost:8080/people/2
 public String getUsersList(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
List<User> userList = userController.getUserList(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", userList);
  return "people/list";
 }

Comment: @VitaliyM.V. а, ну да. Что то я не подумал о том, что можно через адресную строку передать. Спасибо

Comment: Вы используете шаблонизатор, а по другому только через JS и ajaxApp...